# Traced vector has sloppy outline

Tags: adobe-illustrator, vector-graphics

I have used Illustrator to trace a shape for me, but the resulting vector is rendered untidily. It seems like a rendering glitch, as if Illustrator tries to render the shape's outline using a crude polygon.

How can I fix that?
I need illustrator to properly use the specified 0.001pt width, because that's what my laser cutter understands. If I use e.g. 0.005pt line width, the effect is less serious, and with 0.01pt it is even less visible - but not entirely gone.

[image: sloppy curve]

PS: I tried to search for a solution, but I don't even know what the proper terminology for such an artifact is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As a note, the artifacts that you're seeing on the *Mac* are due to GPU Preview, which can cause issues with fine lines.

If you press <kbd>CMD</kbd> + <kbd>E</kbd> you can switch between CPU and GPU preview.

You'll see the issue go away on CPU preview.

The Windows machine may not have a compatible GPU to support GPU acceleration, so it will always display in CPU preview.

In any event, this is a display artifact only, will not show if exported, even in raster format.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that Illustrator on OS X (which is what I've been using) just renders this stroke width very poorly.
On a Windows installation of Illustrator this all looked flawless, and my laser cutter ended up accepting this drawing without problems.